# Organic Material Impedance and Needed Power Requirements

Tags: power, impedance

I'm attempting to determine the power requirements to essentially boil/burn long running, deep weed root systems similar to the tech used by https://rootwave.com/technology/. I'm in the beginning stages of such an endeavor, as an amateur in electronics my thoughts on what step to take first is to determine the impedance level of said root type I'd like to boil/burn before determining power requirements. Is this the right approach? If so, given said impedance (TBD) how do I then determine power needs to reach a level sufficient enough?

Comment: I know nothing about the technique but if I was studying it I would start with a lab power supply, set the voltage to 30 V and current limit to whatever the max is and connect to the plant and a very good earth rod. That would give you a feel for the sort of impedance you're dealing with. From that you can work out what voltage you'll need to drive, say, 100 A through the root. Let us know what you find.

Comment: Thanks for the input! According to RootWave they're using ~8000 volts. My gut tells me that this is close to the truth considering they're sending electricity through organic material. Are you aware of lab power supplies capable of such?

Comment: If you're depending on thermal effects, the amount of power will depend on the thermal conductivity of the soil, amount of water present and the thermal mass. Probably the power and voltage vary widely depending on soil conditions (e.g. heating wet soil will be much harder compared to dry).  Start by researching the temperatures you need, the conductivity and thermal masses of the soil conditions and weeds you're interested in, and then do some math or simulations to work out roughly the energy requirements.  Some experiments aren't a bad idea either for the hard to calculate things.

Comment: @user1850479 thanks for the input, great observations. In my mind the electricity would be heating/boiling the root itself, not the necessarily the soil around it. Obviously temperature of the soil will affect it but I'm wondering if there's a need to study the "conductivity" of the soil vs. the root material itself or maybe this is just a misunderstanding.

Comment: It depends.  If you can apply very high power, then the conductivity of the soil won't matter because you'll heat up fast enough that thermal conduction can be neglected. If you want to apply lower power, then thermal conduction will begin to be much larger factor since there will be time for heat to conduct out of the root into the soil.

Comment: This definitely needs to happen in quick fashion or it's not helpful to solving the problem which is essentially doing what rootwave does. According to their marketing material (I know companies can and do lie) it is fast acting. Given that conduction can be limited I'll go with higher power. I'll start by researching a specific use case of mine and running numbers/calculations. Thank you very much.